# Поставить выполнение кода на паузу

Tags: python

Друзья, помогите грамотно осуществить паузу в процессе выполнения кода python по определенной клавише, допустим это будет клавиша "P" И по этой самой клавише нужно возобновить выполнение кода. (Если это вообще возможно)
Заранее спасибо
Код:

```
import keyboard
    import pyautogui
    import time
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        keyboard.press("1")
        sleep(1)
        keyboard.press("t")
        sleep(1)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Запуск..')
        keyboard.release("t")
        keyboard.write("Привет всем!")
        sleep(5)
        keyboard.press("ENTER")
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'Стоп!')
        sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(button='right')
        pyautogui.moveTo(816, 528, 0.5)
        pyautogui.click(button='left')
        pyautogui.moveTo(851, 401, 0.5)
        pyautogui.click(button='left')
        sleep(5)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Покажите код, который нужно остановить

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Добавил

Answer (score 0):

keyboard.wait() должен помочь справится с вашей задачей.

```
import keyboard

print("пауза уже работает...")
print('чтобы отключить паузу нажмите кнопку эскейп')
keyboard.wait("esc")

print("ваш код после паузы")
```

Можете написать любую кнопку для снятия паузы.